Rambam and a non-Jew receiving Prophecy or Ruach Hakodesh?
Can anyone tell which of the Rambam works where he says, a non-Jew can receive Prophecy and Ruach Hakodesh? I may be thinking of the Tanya which is not by Rambam.

Pretty sure it's not in Tanya.

Isn't it apparent from the story of Bilam?

Don't recall if he spells it out explicitly however based on his understanding of prophecy as a natural faculty if the criteria are met (moral and intellectual perfection) it is open to all unless God actively withholds it

But where did he write that

Think in yesodei hatorah 7 and guide 2:32, need to double check

Moreh Nevukhim 2:32
But if a person, perfect in his intellectual and moral faculties, and also perfect, as far as possible, in his imaginative faculty, prepares himself in the manner which will be described, he must become a prophet; for prophecy is a natural faculty of man. It is impossible that a man who has the capacity for prophecy should prepare himself for it without attaining it, just as it is impossible that a person with a healthy constitution should be fed well, and yet not properly assimilate his food; and the like.

משנה תורה דפוסים יסודי התורה ז':א'
אָדָם שֶׁהוּא מְמֻלָּא בְּכׇל הַמִּדּוֹת הָאֵלּוּ שָׁלֵם בְּגוּפוֹ, כְּשֶׁיִּכָּנֵס לַפַּרְדֵּס וְיִמָּשֵׁךְ בְּאוֹתָן הָעִנְיָנִים הַגְּדוֹלִים הָרְחוֹקִים, וְתִהְיֶה לוֹ דֵּעָה נְכוֹנָה לְהָבִין וּלְהַשִּׂיג וְהוּא מִתְקַדֵּשׁ וְהוֹלֵךְ וּפוֹרֵשׁ מִדַּרְכֵי כְּלַל הָעָם הַהוֹלְכִים בְּמַחֲשַׁכֵּי הַזְּמַן, וְהוֹלֵךְ וּמְזָרֵז עַצְמוֹ וּמְלַמֵּד נַפְשׁוֹ שֶׁלֹּא תִּהְיֶה לוֹ מַחֲשָׁבָה כְּלָל בְּאֶחָד מִדְּבָרִים בְּטֵלִים וְלֹא מֵהַבְלֵי הַזְּמַן וְתַחְבּוּלוֹתָיו, . .   מִיָּד רוּחַ הַקֹּדֶשׁ שׁוֹרָה עָלָיו.

Related: Can a convert be a prophet?

Tanna de-Bei Eliyahu Rabbah 9 says (in translation): "I testify on Myself heaven and earth, whether man or woman, whether gentile or Jew, whether slaveman or slavewoman, everyone according to his actions, the Ruach Hakodesh will dwell on him" (emphasis mine). (Thanks to @ray' and his answer to "Can a convert be a prophet?", for bringing the quote to my attention.)

Thank you for the answers
